# Meaning of "Which two of the following...?" versus "Which of the two following...?"

Tags: semantics

I've just taken a multiple-choice test and one of the questions read like this:

> "Which of the following two statements about effectiveness of control measures are false?"

To answer this question, 5 statements were presented, of which I was requested to tick all the ones I thought were true.

Since 2 of the 5 statements were false, shouldn't the question have been written as:

> "Which two of the following statements about effectiveness of control measures are false?"

Apologies if this question is trivial, but I'm just looking for reassurance, since I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: It sounds as if you may be right, but in that case it should perhaps have been 'Which two of the following FIVE statements about effectiveness of control measures are false?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second variant is definitely correct. The first one states there are two statements, but actually you say there are five.

The second phrase allows for any number of statements, of which two will be false.

So yes - you are right.